# Spring Security Get Authentication on Session TimeOut : Authentication object is returning NULL on session timeout

Tags: spring-security

I'm using spring/spring-security 3.1 and want to take some action depends on the authorities in ATHENTICATION object whenever session is timed out.AUTHENTICATION object is null on session timeout.

Here are the files for reference:

security config:

```
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"  success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <!-- Custom filter to deny unwanted users even though registered -->
    <custom-filter ref="blacklistFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />

    <!-- Custom filter for username, password and domain. The real customization is  done in the customAuthenticationManager -->
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

</http>
```

Note: tried with "invalidate-session="false"" as well.

and my custom LogoutSuccessHandler:

public class EnterpriseLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler{

```
@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    for(GrantedAuthority authority: authentication.getAuthorities()){
        if(authority.getAuthority()!=null)
            logger.debug("THE CURRENT AUTHORITY FOR THE SESSION IS : {} ",authority.getAuthority().toString());
        else
            logger.debug("THE CURRENT AUTHORITY FOR THE SESSION IS authority.getAuthority(): NULL ");

        if(authority.getAuthority()!=null && authority.getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase(Operational.SPRING_SECURITY.LOGIN_SOURCE_BEACON)){
            loginSource = authority.getAuthority().toString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, there is the question how I can obtain Authentication object on the session timeout.

Can some help me to find out the solution for the above problem.

Thanks in advance.